# Splitting 12 assorted items into four representative groups

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In room there are 
4 Cubes - (Red,Blue,White,Green)
4 Balls - (Red,Blue,White,Green)
4 Circles - (Red,Blue,White,Green)
How many ways we can split the 12 items into 4 group, each group should contain at least 1 
cube, 1 ball and 1 circle, and each group should have 3 different colors objects.

Comment: **Hint**: How many ways are there to select just the first group of 3 objects?

Comment: $$\binom41 \binom31 \binom21 $$

 = 4*3*2=24

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you can pick the first group in $24$ ways.  Now you are left with three of each shape and there will be one color common to all the shapes. You have to pick one of that color or you are stuck at the end, so there are $3$ (pick the shape with the unused color) 3(ways to pick the colors of the other shapes)$=9$  Three of these leave you with a color combination like $BW,RG,RG$ with two matching pairs.  There are two ways to sort this out.  The other six leave you with a color combination like $BW,WG,RG$  There are two  ways to sort this out-the pick of item from $WG$ determines the rest and picking the other one. So there are $24\cdot 9 \cdot 2 =432$ total ways if you consider different orders of picking the groups different.  If not, we divide by $4!$ orders of picking groups to get $18$